# Is there a way count(if) query in QueryDsl?

Tags: java, mysql, querydsl

I want to result like that query.

```
SELECT 
  book_id, 
  COUNT(member_id), 
  COUNT(if(returned = 1, 1, null)) 
...
```

There is case-when query in QueryDSL, But it is not what I want exactly.
I can't find any ways to use COUNT IF query.
So I wonder is there any ways about using COUNT() query that used COUNT IF function in querydsl.

https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-count/

```
JPQLQuery<?> countDto = getQueryDsl().createQuery()
  .select(bookRental.bookId, bookRental.memberId.count(), bookRental.memberId.count(...)
  .from(bookRental)
  .where(bookId.in(bookIds))
  .groupBy(bookRental.bookId);
```

Or Should I use CaseBuilder()?

```
new CaseBuilder()
    .when(bookRental.returned.eq(true))
    .then(bookRental.memberId.count(1))
    .otherwise(0)
```

Comment: try SUM(returned = 1)

Comment: Can you explain more detail?

Comment: SUM(returned = 1) adds 1 if the condition is met or 0 if not so you get a count of all returned = 1 but it seems querdsl you must do something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/21261701/5193536

Comment: Thanks for the link, I will try to.

Answer (score 0):

bookRental.memberId.eq('test').count().as("bookRentalCount")

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).